# Ability to have verification screen which returns to last activity on the stack when finish and finish whole app when back press

Tags: android

I am struggling with the concept of creating the verification screen in my app (which is refreshing the state and require user to provide valid PIN)

Here are two important navigation requirements for that screen:

- I want that verification screen to close when the PIN is valid and when finish return to the last opened screen on the stack
- When user tap the back press on that verification screen I want to close the whole app (so that there is nothing in the background). So the whole previous stack of screens are closed/finished

**What I've tried:**
It seems that to be able to close the whole app when the activity finish (with all previous activities/screens) that last activity should be started with additional flag `android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` set to the `Intent`

But how i can remain the whole previous stack when the verification screen passed with valid PIN (and the verification activity is finished by calling `FragmentActivity.finish()`)?

Another concept is to use `finishAffinity()`, but how to handle the case, when the previous screens are belonging to some different affinity process in my app? I want to close all present affinity processes (when there are multiple)

Comment: Have one activity and several fragments/composables per screen, not several activities.

Comment: That is not possible as I have big app with plenty of activities, so there is no way i can refactor that. So beside that, is there any ability?

Answer (score 1):

You can control when the user clicks on the back, so for the case where the flow is successful you just call finish() and you are done. For the flow where the user taps on back button , what you can do is start a new dummy activity but call it as a single top that deletes all other activities before and on the create method of such activity you could call finish() .

It's not a classy solution but it should work

Comment: Thanks I will try that but why exactly calling the dummy activity as single top? Should it be also called with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK?

Comment: Yes , I said it poorly on the answer. But yes, clear task is the way to go. No need to specify anything else.

Comment: Ok, but I think I must use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK instead of FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. Otherwise it is not working